# Permanent link to media library files?

Tags: links, wordpress, pdf

If I upload a .pdf file to the media library it gets a link like:

```
http://myblog.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/myfile.pdf
```

Is it possible to make a permanent link to it (e.g. the link will not change if I replace `myfile.pdf` with a new version next month or later)?

Either:

```
http://myblog.files.wordpress.com/something/myfile.pdf
```

or just

```
http://myblog.files.wordpress.com/myfile.pdf
```

would be fine.

Comment: You may ask this question on [WordPress Stack Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com). A meta filed with custom permalinks should be possible for attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, you are changing the file, the link has to change.

WordPress creates link based on the date of upload of the file.

What you can do is: use a url-shortner service such as [tiny.cc](http://www.tiny.cc), create a link to redirect to your myfile.pdf and then each time you update your file, you can have the very same tiny.cc link to redirect to your new file.

Comment: This is wrong. You can change permalinks for uploads, even for single ones, and you can replace existing files without changing the URL. WordPress does not create links based on the date, if you haven’t told it to do that.